Aggregate across rows in R, ignoring NA values
I have a pseudo table like this.
dat <- data.frame(
  colA = c("factor1", "factor1", "factor1", "factor1","factor2", "factor2","factor2", "factor2"),
  colB = c("a", "a", "a", NA, "a", "a", "a", NA), 
  colC = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 2,4,5,6))
dat
     colA colB colC
1 factor1    a    1
2 factor1    a    1
3 factor1    a    1
4 factor1 <NA>    5
5 factor2    a    2
6 factor2    a    4
7 factor2    a    5
8 factor2 <NA>    6

I want to sum the values in colC, group_by by colA, but only including rows where colB does not have (NA). After that, I'd like to calculate the frequency of the resulting sums.
My desired outputs will be:



colA
colB
colC




factor1
a
3


factor1
NA
5


factor2
a
11


factor2
NA
6






colA
colB
Freq




factor1
a
0.375


factor1
NA
0.625


factor2
a
0.65


factor2
NA
0.35



Any suggestions for this? Thanks in advance!

library(dplyr)
> dat %>% 
    summarise(colC = sum(colC, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(colA, colB)) %>% 
    mutate(Freq = colC / sum(colC, na.rm = TRUE), .by = colA)
     colA colB colC      Freq
1 factor1    a    3 0.3750000
2 factor1 <NA>    5 0.6250000
3 factor2    a   11 0.6470588
4 factor2 <NA>    6 0.3529412


You can get both measures in 1 data frame with:
dat %>%
  summarise(colC = sum(colC), .by = c(colA, colB)) %>%
  mutate(Freq = colC / sum(colC), .by = colA)

or if you need the 2 separate data frames:
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  summarise(colC = sum(colC), .by = c(colA, colB))

dat %>%
  summarise(colC = sum(colC), .by = c(colA, colB)) %>%
  mutate(Freq = colC / sum(colC), .by = colA) %>%
  select(-colC)


Your first alternative duplicates mine

library(tidyverse)
dat |>
  group_by(colA, is.na(colB)) |>
  summarise(colC = sum(colC)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(
    colC_total = sum(colC), .by = colA,
    pct_colC = colC / colC_total
  )

